# Dictionary "Command' Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a bot that does a very simple task, it adds points to a member in the channel for the time the bot is live, in a temporary context. Trying to accomplish this without databases, because I don't need a permanent record of these points. I seem to have come very close to a solution combining a lot of references I've found over the internet. In essence, I create a dictionary based on the member ID and add 1 that key value pair whenever I use the give command, however, I keep getting the error listed below, I appreciate your time and please if someone can explain to me WHY this sub scriptable error happens with my code, Thank you and have a great day.

Adding my code below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from collections import defaultdict


TOKEN = '#code would go here.'

bot = Bot('!')
points = defaultdict(int)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)

    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.content == "hello":
        # SENDS A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL.
        await message.channel.send("FIX CONTEXT")

    # INCLUDES THE COMMANDS FOR THE BOT. WITHOUT THIS LINE, YOU CANNOT TRIGGER YOUR COMMANDS.
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def give(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    points[member.id] += 1
    ctx.send("{} now has {} radiation".format(member.mention, points[member.id]))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def points(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    ctx.send("{} has {} radiation".format(member.mention, points[member.id]))


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The main thing I don't understand about my code is the line **Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable**

```
We have logged in as RadiationTracker#7562
AdamKostandy: !!give AdamKostandy#9900 (ffg-game-chat)
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "!give" is not found
AdamKostandy: !give AdamKostandy#9900 (ffg-game-chat)
Ignoring exception in command give:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Adam/Documents/GitHub/Discord-Bot/main.py", line 34, in give
    points[member.id] += 1
TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable
AdamKostandy: !points AdamKostandy#9900 (ffg-game-chat)
Ignoring exception in command points:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Adam/Documents/GitHub/Discord-Bot/main.py", line 39, in points
    ctx.send("{} has {} radiation".format(member.mention, points[member.id]))
TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You have a global variable `points` and also a method `points`. Rename one of them so that python can know which one you are referring to

Comment: Annddd this did the trick thank you so much!